# Automating Database Updating

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, ssis, automation

I want to create a task of some sort (maybe using Visual Studio 2010?) that will allow be to update existing items in a preexisting database table (using SQL Server 2005). I have a stored procedure to get the information that I want to update but am having some trouble figuring out how to use it most efficiently. I considered using a Visual Studio 2005 SSIS package but I couldn't quite figure out  how to use UPDATE through the package.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: The `OLE DB Command` Component is the way to go. You can put an update statement in there with a limiting where clause. The command will execute for every row in your flow.

Comment: One thing to note if you do go the route of `OLE DB Command` is that will fire one update per row flowing through the dataflow which is in contrast to the bulk insert operations you usually perform w/SSIS

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean there. Do you mean that only one attribute per row will be updated or just one attribute at a time? Thanks for your reply